# Pandas Groupby Ranges when ranges are not continuous

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id    |   A   |   B   |   C
------------------------------
1     |  0.1  |  1.2  |  100    
2     |  0.2  |  1.4  |  200    
3     |  0.3  |  1.6  |  300    
4     |  0.4  |  1.8  |  400    
5     |  0.5  |  2.0  |  500
6     |  0.6  |  2.2  |  600    
7     |  0.7  |  2.4  |  700    
8     |  0.8  |  2.6  |  800    
9     |  0.9  |  2.8  |  900    
10    |  1.0  |  3.0  |  1000    
11    |  1.1  |  3.2  |  1100
```

I want to use groupby to this dataframe to group it by a range of increments for the column 'A' or 'B'.
But the ranges are not consecutive nor exclusive, they are like this:

```
(0,1.1.1]
(0.2,1.1]
(0.4,1.1]
(0.6,1.1]
(0.8,1.1]
(1.0,1.1]
```

Then apply it some functions (mean and sum), so my end result will be kind of like this:

```
          | A_mean | B_mean | C_sum
A_bins    |        |        |  
-------------------------------------
(0,1.1.1] |  0.6   |  2.2   | 6600
(0.2,1.1] |  0.7   |  2.4   | 6300
(0.4,1.1] |  0.8   |  2.6   | 5600
(0.6,1.1] |  0.9   |  2.8   | 4500
(0.8,1.1] |  1.0   |  3.0   | 3000
(1.0,1.1] |  1.1   |  3.2   | 1100
```

I was thinking of trying `groupby` with `pd.cut()` but I think `pd.cut()` won't be able to work with those intervals.

So, is there any way that I can achieve that with those kinds of ranges? Or any kind of ranges that are not in the form of something like: `np.arange(0, 1.1+0.05, 0.2)`

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using the apply function to generate the metrics you need.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A_bins': [(0.1,1.1), (0.2,1.1), (0.4,1.1), (0.6,1.1), (0.8,1.1), (1.0,1.1)]})

def get_sum(row): # this is where the logic for your metrics goes
   return df.loc[(row['A_bins'][0]<df['A']) & (row['A_bins'][1]>=df['A']),'C'].sum()

df2['C_sum'] = df2.apply(get_sum, axis = 1)
print (df2)
```

Output:

```
       A_bins   C_sum
0  (0.1, 1.1)  6500.0
1  (0.2, 1.1)  6300.0
2  (0.4, 1.1)  5600.0
3  (0.6, 1.1)  4500.0
4  (0.8, 1.1)  3000.0
5  (1.0, 1.1)  1100.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know you could use the apply function to do that, I'll keep that in mind for future problems, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to transpose it and then try a range function on it if it exists( I have never used range() and can’t test now ):

```
df.T.range()
```

Instead of mean you can try describe() or min()/max().